# Is there a JS library to provide xpath capacities to IE

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xpath

I am doing a lot of XPath with "normal & modern" browser (FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari...) but I'm looking for a javascript library which allow IE to support `document.evaluate()` method.

Does it exist ? I know there are some similar questions in StackOverflow, but they were asked & answered many years ago.

The idea is to: factorize the code in reading xpath & also producing (same) xpath.

---

**Update**, 8th August 2011:

I find the lib proposed by @ExtremeCoder here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/html-xpath/

This is really what I need (it "override" document.evaluate only for IE)... but it creates bug on chrome & it doesn't work more on IE :/

---

**Update** 29 August 2012 (yeah, one year after).

I test a wide range of library. A lot of those which override document.evaluate are not very strong or suffer for different bugs.
I finally use the good old Google Ajax XSLT without the XSLT part ;)

http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/

(so I validate your answer @Cheeso)

By the way a lot of  (or all) these libraries are not anymore maintained.

---

**Update** again, 28th September 2012:

Google **starts** another XPath lib project.
I dont test it yet but it seems promising and updated.
http://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/

As usual, thanks Microsoft (for explorer 8/9/10) (sic!), please learn to support basic standards and other browsers behaviors.

Comment: Just curious is this with respect to developing web apps (or some other apps) using XPath or testing web apps using XPath locators in Selenium, etc.? Don't quite get the context from the question here.

Comment: It was to build a JS/PHP scrap tool in my previous company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
// xpath.js
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// a cross-browser xpath class.
// Derived form code at http://jmvidal.cse.sc.edu/talks/javascriptxml/xpathexample.html.
//
// Tested in Chrome, IE9, and FF6.0.2
//
// Author     : Dino
// Created    : Sun Sep 18 18:39:58 2011
// Last-saved : <2011-September-19 15:07:20>
//
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

/*jshint browser:true */

(function(globalScope) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * The first argument to this constructor is the text of the XPath expression.
     *
     * If the expression uses any XML namespaces, the second argument must
     * be a JavaScript object that maps namespace prefixes to the URLs that define
     * those namespaces.  The properties of this object are taken as prefixes, and
     * the values associated to those properties are the URLs.
     *
     * There's no way to specify a non-null default XML namespace. You need to use
     * prefixes in order to reference a non-null namespace in a query.
     *
     */

    var expr = function(xpathText, namespaces) {
        var prefix;
        this.xpathText = xpathText;    // Save the text of the expression
        this.namespaces = namespaces || null;  // And the namespace mapping

        if (document.createExpression) {
            this.xpathExpr = true;
            // I tried using a compiled xpath expression, it worked on Chrome,
            // but it did not work on FF6.0.2.  Threw various exceptions.
            // So I punt on "compiling" the xpath and just evaluate it.
            //
            // This flag serves only to store the result of the check.
            //

                // document.createExpression(xpathText,
                // // This function is passed a
                // // namespace prefix and returns the URL.
                // function(prefix) {
                //     return namespaces[prefix];
                // });
        }
        else {
            // assume IE and convert the namespaces object into the
            // textual form that IE requires.
            this.namespaceString = "";
            if (namespaces !== null) {
                for(prefix in namespaces) {
                    // Add a space if there is already something there
                    if (this.namespaceString.length>1) this.namespaceString += ' ';
                    // And add the namespace
                    this.namespaceString += 'xmlns:' + prefix + '="' +
                        namespaces[prefix] + '"';
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * This is the getNodes() method of XPath.Expression.  It evaluates the
     * XPath expression in the specified context.  The context argument should
     * be a Document or Element object.  The return value is an array
     * or array-like object containing the nodes that match the expression.
     */
    expr.prototype.getNodes = function(xmlDomCtx) {
        var self = this, a, i,
            doc = xmlDomCtx.ownerDocument;

        // If the context doesn't have ownerDocument, it is the Document
        if (doc === null) doc = xmlDomCtx;

        if (this.xpathExpr) {
            // could not get a compiled XPathExpression to work in FF6
            // var result = this.xpathExpr.evaluate(xmlDomCtx,
            //     // This is the result type we want
            //     XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
            //     null);

            var result = doc.evaluate(this.xpathText,
                xmlDomCtx,
                function(prefix) {
                    return self.namespaces[prefix];
                },
                XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
                null);

            // Copy the results into an array.
            a = [];
            for(i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
                a.push(result.snapshotItem(i));
            }
            return a;
        }
        else {
            // evaluate the expression using the IE API.
            try {
                // This is IE-specific magic to specify prefix-to-URL mapping
                doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
                doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", this.namespaceString);

                // In IE, the context must be an Element not a Document,
                // so if context is a document, use documentElement instead
                if (xmlDomCtx === doc) xmlDomCtx = doc.documentElement;
                // Now use the IE method selectNodes() to evaluate the expression
                return xmlDomCtx.selectNodes(this.xpathText);
            }
            catch(e2) {
                throw "XPath is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }
    };


    /**
     * This is the getNode() method of XPath.Expression.  It evaluates the
     * XPath expression in the specified context and returns a single matching
     * node (or null if no node matches).  If more than one node matches,
     * this method returns the first one in the document.
     * The implementation differs from getNodes() only in the return type.
     */
    expr.prototype.getNode = function(xmlDomCtx) {
        var self = this,
                doc = xmlDomCtx.ownerDocument;
        if (doc === null) doc = xmlDomCtx;
        if (this.xpathExpr) {

            // could not get compiled "XPathExpression" to work in FF4
            // var result =
            //     this.xpathExpr.evaluate(xmlDomCtx,
            //     // We just want the first match
            //     XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
            //     null);

            var result = doc.evaluate(this.xpathText,
                xmlDomCtx,
                function(prefix) {
                    return self.namespaces[prefix];
                },
                XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
                null);
            return result.singleNodeValue;
        }
        else {
            try {
                doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
                doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", this.namespaceString);
                if (xmlDomCtx == doc) xmlDomCtx = doc.documentElement;
                return xmlDomCtx.selectSingleNode(this.xpathText);
            }
            catch(e) {
                throw "XPath is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }
    };


    var getNodes = function(context, xpathExpr, namespaces) {
        return (new globalScope.XPath.Expression(xpathExpr, namespaces)).getNodes(context);
    };

    var getNode  = function(context, xpathExpr, namespaces) {
        return (new globalScope.XPath.Expression(xpathExpr, namespaces)).getNode(context);
    };


    /**
     * XPath is a global object, containing three members.  The
     * Expression member is a class modelling an Xpath expression.  Use
     * it like this:
     *
     *   var xpath1 = new XPath.Expression("/kml/Document/Folder");
     *   var nodeList = xpath1.getNodes(xmldoc);
     *
     *   var xpath2 = new XPath.Expression("/a:kml/a:Document",
     *                                   { a : 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' });
     *   var node = xpath2.getNode(xmldoc);
     *
     * The getNodes() and getNode() methods are just utility methods for
     * one-time use. Example:
     *
     *   var oneNode = XPath.getNode(xmldoc, '/root/favorites');
     *
     *   var nodeList = XPath.getNodes(xmldoc, '/x:derp/x:twap', { x: 'urn:0190djksj-xx'} );
     *
     */

    // place XPath into the global scope.
    globalScope.XPath = {
        Expression : expr,
        getNodes   : getNodes,
        getNode    : getNode
    };

}(this));
```

You can use the same code in all browsers, though it is not `document.evaluate()`, not directly.  Instead you use it like this:

```
      var xpath = new XPath.Expression("/a:kml/a:Document",
                                      { a : 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' });
      var node = xpath.getNode(xmldoc);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dareobasanjo/archive/2004/04/20/116815.aspx

I think that should do it.

--

Appologies, I think this website is actually exactly what you're looking for: http://www.dashop.de/blog/en/dev/JavaScript/content/XPath/JavaScript-XPath-Implementation.html

Comment: Quite old, no? And the link is dead :/

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added a new website that I includes a link to a library for what you need. The link on that one is not dead.

Comment: Ok. I will test it. But I'm not sure if I can override the document.evaluate in IE.(which mean same current default code for all browser (yes, nice dream))

Comment: Indeed it's not exactly what I'm looking because it's need to double my code. But I am not sure if any js lib can do it with this *** browser called IE.
Update: curious behavior / hard to launch. I will look for another lib

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, you could find MochiKit's Selector API useful: http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/Selector.html

It does all I've also used xpath for, and it's pretty lightweight and works on all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most recent cross-browser implementation of XPath in Javascript: https://github.com/andrejpavlovic/xpathjs

It is fully functional and unit tested, and has great support. The coolest part is that it also supports namespaces!

Comment: Seems nice but I changed job a year ago and I don't do xpath stuff regularly. If a SO user can also test it, I would be happy to update my question and validate this answer.